# Problem with Big Query filters when your data has a null in a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, sql-null

I am facing a strange issue starting today in Google Big Query. The below query is returning no records. I did not see this issue yesterday

```
WITH Q1 AS (SELECT 'XC1' AS XC , NULL AS NU 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'XC2' AS XC , 'TAB' AS NU )

SELECT * FROM Q1
WHERE NU != 'TAB'
```

It should ideally show the record with XC = XC1 but it does not return any records.

Are you all facing the same issue ? Please let us know soon as we are facing a bigger issue in other areas.

Can you suggest what is going on here ?

Comment: can you clarify - your question is why this happened today while was working yesterday? or you asking how to fix your query?

Comment: My question is why this worked yesterday but not today.

Comment: that was my guess. Let's hope someone from BigQuery Team will catch this question and provide answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option to address this case for BigQuery Standard SQL is

```
WHERE IFNULL(NU != 'TAB', TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a null-safe comparison. In standard SQL, you would typically use operator `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`:

```
SELECT * FROM Q1 WHERE NU IS DISTINCT FROM 'TAB'
```

Unfortunately few database support this syntax, and BQ is not one of them. So we need to resort a condition expression:

```
SELECT * FROM Q1 WHERE NU IS NULL OR NU != 'TAB'
```

Comment: OP stated - I did not see this issue yesterday

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: for me, I cannot see how OP's query would ever work. But... you know BQ far better than me!

Comment: yes. i am just trying to figure out what IS the focus of OP's question. Is it change in behavior (assuming it is really changed) or how to fix

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't have a `NULL`-safe operator.  It does have a similar method, though:

```
where not ((nu = 'TAB') is false)
```

I will admit that the `or` solution is probably clearer.